# can't bootstrap in Landscape OpenStack Autopilot

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I use MAAS to make landscape openstack outopilot. I use `sudo openstack-install` but failed. This is my commands.log

```
INFO • 01-28 11:21:33 [LINE:156, FUNC:<module>] • cloudinstall • cloud-install $
DEBUG • 01-28 11:21:33 [LINE:111, FUNC:main_loop] • cloudinstall.install • loop$
INFO • 01-28 11:21:33 [LINE:71, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Get $
DEBUG • 01-28 11:21:33 [LINE:93, FUNC:_build_widget] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog •$
DEBUG • 01-28 11:21:39 [LINE:111, FUNC:submit] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Callb$
INFO • 01-28 11:21:39 [LINE:71, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Choo$
DEBUG • 01-28 11:21:41 [LINE:214, FUNC:submit] • cloudinstall.ui • Callback on $
INFO • 01-28 11:21:41 [LINE:71, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Plea$
DEBUG • 01-28 11:21:41 [LINE:93, FUNC:_build_widget] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog •$
DEBUG • 01-28 11:26:02 [LINE:111, FUNC:submit] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • Callb$
DEBUG • 01-28 11:26:02 [LINE:81, FUNC:_save_lds_creds] • cloudinstall.landscape$
INFO • 01-28 11:26:02 [LINE:71, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Wait$
DEBUG • 01-28 11:27:13 [LINE:650, FUNC:ssh_genkey] • cloudinstall.utils • ssh k$
INFO • 01-28 11:27:13 [LINE:71, FUNC:status_context] • cloudinstall.core • Boot$
DEBUG • 01-28 11:27:13 [LINE:139, FUNC:do_install] • cloudinstall.multi_install$
DEBUG • 01-28 12:27:34 [LINE:145, FUNC:do_install] • cloudinstall.multi_install$
DEBUG • 01-28 12:27:34 [LINE:51, FUNC:global_exchandler] • cloudinstall.utils •$
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 66, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_cont$
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 146, in do_in$
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
```

How can I fix it's ?

Comment: Are you able to `juju bootstrap` outside of the installer to a node in your MAAS environment? It'd be interesting to see if the bootstrap is failing and not the installer. Also are you behind any proxies?

Comment: I not behind any proxies. Even though not use installer, bootstrap failed too.
ERROR bootstrap failed: waited for 10m0s without being able to connect: /var/lib/juju/nonce.txt does not exist
Stopping instance...
Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
ERROR waited for 10m0s without being able to connect: /var/lib/juju/nonce.txt does not exist

Comment: if juju is failing to bootstrap outside of the installer then this seems like a different issue not related to the installer. can you acquire and start a node via maas and see if you can connect to the system? Also once connected are you able to get out to the internet from that machine?

Comment: oh, yes, my node can't connect to internet

Answer (score 2):

I've seen anecdotal evidence on the juju mailing list that using juju from the juju stable ppa resolved this issue for at least one person.

Here's the [mailing list post](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju/2014-May/003849.html)

Comment: It's still failed.
2015-01-30 04:21:43 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:323 failed to bootstrap environment: waited for 10m0s without being able to connect: Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: That is an ssh error, looks juju is using an incorrect ssh key for logging into the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be issue like mine, described here [Failed to bootstrap during Openstack autopilot installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714767/faild-to-bootstrap-during-openstack-autopilot-installation)

Update your libraries with these command and start landscape installation again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Also update your images of MAAS, through maas web ui.